# Assigning user to Active Directory native app in Powershell - 'C

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory

I can't add it in the portal because it's a native app and they aren't allowing that. I tried to follow the steps on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduserapproleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0) page:

```
# Get the service principal of the app to assign the user to
$servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "<Your app's display name>"

# Get the user to be assigned
$user = Get-AzureADUser -searchstring "<Your user's UPN>"

# Create the user app role assignment
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id ([Guid]::Empty)
```

I get the following error: `New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.`

But when I check it it says that's not true:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $user.ObjectId -ne $null
False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually you're confusing your logic. If `something -ne $null` returns false, then that something is equal to $null. I suggest checking if `$user` has any value at all, and if it doesn't look in to whether your `Get-AzureADUser` command/parameters are correct.

Comment: Thanks. I was in the wrong directory. You can post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused the logic result due to the double negative. For example

```
$null -ne $null
```

Returns "false" because $null being not equal to $null is not true. Your test is telling you that $user.ObjectID is indeed `null` per the error. You likely need to confirm `Get-AzureADUser` is returning an object to `$user`.